# Package control не отображается и не дает установить пакеты в Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Недавно столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не могу установить Package Control, его просто нет в списке, когда набираю в командной строке. Решил переустановить Sublime и удалил все папки с зависимостями (работаю на мак). После этого появилась команда для установки Package Control, но при наборе Install Package все равно ничего нет и пакеты установить нельзя. Встречаюсь с этой проблемой впервые и вообще не знаю что делать.
[image]